# What is the syntax to insert one list into another list in python?

Tags: python, list, append, extend

Given two lists:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]
```

What is the syntax to:

1. Insert `x` into `y` such that `y` now looks like `[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]`?
2. Insert all the items of `x` into `y` such that `y` now looks like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`?

Comment: reverse listB, thence [listA.insert(pos,x) for x in [listB]]

Comment: see also this post: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805892/how-to-insert-the-contents-of-one-list-into-another

Comment: @JohnMee Do you mean `listA.insert(pos, x) for x in listB[::-1]`?

Answer (score 415, accepted):

Do you mean `append`?

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y = [4,5,6]
>>> x.append(y)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
```

Or merge?

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y = [4,5,6]
>>> x + y
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> x.extend(y)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Is that in place or yields a new instance?

Comment: `x.extend(y)` is in place, `x+y` is returning new list.   And `x += y`, which was not mentioned here, is similar to the extend.

Answer (score 134):

The question does not make clear what exactly you want to achieve.

List has the `append` method, which appends its argument to the list:

```
>>> list_one = [1,2,3]
>>> list_two = [4,5,6]
>>> list_one.append(list_two)
>>> list_one
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
```

There's also the `extend` method, which appends *items* from the list you pass as an argument:

```
>>> list_one = [1,2,3]
>>> list_two = [4,5,6]
>>> list_one.extend(list_two)
>>> list_one
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

And of course, there's the `insert` method which acts similarly to `append` but allows you to specify the insertion point:

```
>>> list_one.insert(2, list_two)
>>> list_one
[1, 2, [4, 5, 6], 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

To extend a list at a specific insertion point you can use list slicing (thanks, @florisla):

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> l[2:2] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> l
[1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c', 3, 4, 5]
```

List slicing is quite flexible as it allows to replace a range of entries in a list with a range of entries from another list:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> l[2:4] = ['a', 'b', 'c'][1:3]
>>> l
[1, 2, 'b', 'c', 5]
```

Comment: If you want to 'extend' to a specific insertion point, you can use list slicing syntax (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7376026/1075152)

Comment: @florisla's comment should be the accepted answer. It's the only way to insert a list into another list in place at an arbitrary location (not just at the end).

Comment: @weaver While it's the only solution to do *that* (extend at a specific index), that was not the original question.

Comment: @florisla That's pedantry.

Answer (score 36):

```
foo = [1, 2, 3]
bar = [4, 5, 6]

foo.append(bar) --> [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
foo.extend(bar) --> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: how do you insert bar after 2 and keep it flatten?  `[1,2,4,5,6,3]`

Comment: I've found that this: foo[2:2]=bar  generates a flattened list. I learned that because it was not what I wanted.

Answer (score 6):

You can also just do...

```
x += y
```

Comment: This should be a comment on the accepted answer, because that one mentions `x + y` and `x += y` is just the same thing but in place.

Comment: I do not have the reputation to do that, but if someone else can!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add the elements in a list (list2) to the end of other list (list), then you can use the list extend method

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
list.extend(list2)
print list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Or if you want to concatenate two list then you can use + sign

```
list3 = list + list2
print list3
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

If we just do `x.append(y)`, y gets referenced into x such that any changes made to y will affect appended x as well. So if we need to insert only elements, we should do following:

`x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]
x.append(y[:])`