# Adding a dictionary inside a dictionary error

Tags: python, dictionary, pygame

I used the answer here: [syntax for creating a dictionary into another dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817529/syntax-for-creating-a-dictionary-into-another-dictionary-in-python) as a base to what I used.

I, however, get a syntax error and can't see why.

```
player.image_dict = {( 0,2,0,0,0,0):  {'idle' : itertools.cycle
                                                       [(pygame.image.load("images/egg_1.png"),
                                                       pygame.image.load("images/egg_2.png"), 
                                                       pygame.image.load("images/egg_3.png")] },               


                     ( 2,4,0,0,2,5):  {'idle' : itertools.cycle
                                                        ([pygame.image.load("images/leaf_1.png"), 
                                                        pygame.image.load("images/leaf_2.png"), 
                                                        pygame.image.load("images/leaf_3.png"),
                                                        pygame.image.load("images/leaf_4.png")])}}
```

The syntax error refers to the line:

```
pygame.image.load("images/egg_3.png")] },
```

Comment: `itertools.cycle[...]` should be `itertools.cycle([...])`.

Comment: Just an FYI - this is a very poor data structure. If you find yourself embedding too many lists/dicts inside each other - you probably need custom classes, a better way to organize your data, or to rethink your approach. Especially considering those dictionary keys look horrible.

Comment: There will be 6 main keys, with 5 of them having 3 inner keys. The only problem I see with making custom classes is that when I loop the game, I'll have to, as far as my knowledge, have checks to see what the stats are (this is what the 0,2,0,0,0 refers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the opening brackets the wrong way round:

```
itertools.cycle([pygame.image.load("images/egg_1.png"),
                 ...
```

and at the end:

```
...egg_3.png"] ) },
```

Comment: Thanks. Such a silly mistake. This, however, leads to another syntax error:

http://pastebin.com/Hc24sM65

Specific line: ( 2,4,0,0,2,5):  {'idle' : itertools.cycle