# How to insert the contents of one list into another

Tags: list, python

I am trying to combine the contents of two lists, in order to later perform processing on the entire data set.  I initially looked at the built in `insert` function, but it inserts as a list, rather than the contents of the list.

I can slice and append the lists, but is there a cleaner / more Pythonic way of doing what I want than this:

```
array    = ['the', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']
addition = ['quick', 'brown']

array = array[:1] + addition + array[1:]
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can do the following using the slice syntax on the left hand side of an assignment:

```
>>> array = ['the', 'fox', 'jumped', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']
>>> array[1:1] = ['quick', 'brown']
>>> array
['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumped', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']
```

That's about as Pythonic as it gets!

Answer (score 37):

The `extend` method of list object does this, but at the end of the original list.

```
addition.extend(array)
```

Comment: While David's solution was what the OP wanted, yours is what I need all the time. Thanks so much.

Comment: I think the addition should be inside .extend() and array before it.

Answer (score 3):

`insert(i,j)`, where `i` is the index and `j` is what you want to insert, does not add as a list. Instead it adds as a list item:

```
array = ['the', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']
array.insert(1,'brown')
```

The new array would be:

```
array = ['the', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']
```

Answer (score 1):

Leveraging the [splat operator / list unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503331/using-the-splat-operator-with-print) for lists you can do it using

```
array    = ['the', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']
addition = ['quick', 'brown']

# like this
array2    = ['the', *addition, 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']

# or like this
array = [ *array[:1], *addition, *array[1:]]

print(array)
print(array2)
```

to get

```
['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumped', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']
```

The operator got introduces with  [PEP 448: Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448).