# using the * (splat) operator with print

Tags: python, python-2.7

I often use Python's `print` statement to display data. Yes, I know about the `'%s %d' % ('abc', 123)` method, and the `'{} {}'.format('abc', 123)` method, and the `' '.join(('abc', str(123)))` method. I also know that the splat operator (`*`) can be used to expand an iterable into function arguments. However, I can't seem to do that with the `print` statement. Using a list:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print l
[1, 2, 3]
>>> '{} {} {}'.format(*l)
'1 2 3'
>>> print *l
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print *l
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Using a tuple:

```
>>> t = (4, 5, 6)
>>> t
(4, 5, 6)
>>> print t
(4, 5, 6)
>>> '%d %d %d' % t
'4 5 6'
>>> '{} {} {}'.format(*t)
'4 5 6'
>>> print *t
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print *t
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Am I missing something? Is this simply not possible? What exactly are the things that follow `print`? The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) says that a comma-separated list of expressions follow the `print` keyword, but I am guessing this is not the same as a list data type. I did a lot of digging in SO and on the web and did not find a clear explanation for this.

I am using Python 2.7.6.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`print` is a statement in Python 2.x and does not support the `*` syntax.  You can see this from the grammar for `print` listed in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-print_stmt):

```
print_stmt ::=  "print" ([expression ("," expression)* [","]]
                | ">>" expression [("," expression)+ [","]])
```

Notice how there is no option for using `*` after the `print` keyword.

---

However, the `*` syntax *is* supported inside function calls and it just so happens that [`print` is a function in Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).  This means that you could import it from [`__future__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html):

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

and then use:

```
print(*l)
```

Demo:

```
>>> # Python 2.x interpreter
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(*l)
1 2 3
>>>
```

Comment: OK, so it looks like it is simply not permitted by the language definition. I was hoping I was missing something, that somehow the `*` operator would be applied as part of evaluating `print`'s expressions, and that the result would somehow be compatible with `print`. In other words, I was hoping that `*iterable` would be interpreted by `print` as a comma-separated list of expressions, where each expression was an element of the iterable. I guess this would imply that each of those expressions would itself be evaluated, which might lead to code injection, or worse. Perhaps that is the reason.

Comment: The `*` syntax is actually a part of the [function call syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls); it is not an independent operator.  `print` does not support it simply because the language designers didn't decide to make it that way.  There was a proposal recently to expand the `*` syntax to more areas of Python, but it has yet to be implemented.

Comment: Ah. That explains things much further. Thanks. +1.