# Changing specific index's in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Say I had a list:

```
lis = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Would there be any way too take out the first 4 values of the list, make them :

```
[4, 2, 2, 4]
```

and the put them back in the list so the list now looks like

```
[4, 2, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

and do all of this without making the list

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

at the start.

Also if possible, can you make a loop to do this for all the 4 values available.

So that the list now looks like:

```
[4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert the contents of one list into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805892/how-to-insert-the-contents-of-one-list-into-another)

Answer (score 1):

Just do like this:

```
lis1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
# change first 4 index
lis1[:4] = 4,2,2,4
print(lis1)
# [4, 2, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]    

lis2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
# change every 4 index in loop
for i in range(0,len(lis2),4):
    lis2[i:i+4] = 4,2,2,4
print(lis2)
# [4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lis = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
fill = [4, 2, 2, 4]
for i in range(0, len(lis), len(fill)):
    lis[i : i + len(fill)] = fill
print(lis)
```

This outputs:

```
[4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **`itertools.cycle`** and **`itertools.islice`**:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

lis = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

out = list(map(int, islice(cycle('4224'), len(lis))))
print(out)

# [4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4]
```

Or a simpler way (without any imports):

```
lis = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

out = list(map(int, '4224' * (len(lis) // 4)))
print(out)

# [4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def list_function(original_list, list_of_value_to_subst):
    original_list[:len(list_of_value_to_subst)]=list_of_value_to_subst

    print (original_list)

    subst_list = list(map(int, list_of_value_to_subst * (len(original_list) // len(list_of_value_to_subst))))

    print (subst_list)


lis = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
list_of_value_to_subst=[4, 2, 2, 4]

list_function(lis, list_of_value_to_subst)
```

output:

```
[4, 2, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, would be to do the following:

For your first question:

```
lis = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

ins = [4, 2, 2, 4]

lis[:len(ins)] = ins

print(lis)
```

Output:

```
[4, 2, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

For your second question:

```
lis = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

lis = ins * int(len(lis) / len(ins))

print(lis)
```

Output:

```
[4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the list of numbers you want to replace the first part of `lis` with:

```
replace_lis = [4, 2, 2, 4]
```

You can iterate over the length of `replace_lis`, and fill in the index spots in `lis` accordingly:

```
for i in range(len(replace_lis)):
    if i < len(lis):
        lis[i] = replace_lis[i]
```

The `i < len(lis)` is if `replace_lis` could be bigger than `lis`. If there is no chance of that, you can safely omit that if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your original list:

```
lis = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

and you'd like to replace the first 4 items with:
[4, 2, 2, 4]

Let's assign the new values a new variable. Let's call it update. So:

```
update = [4, 2, 2, 4]
```

Here is your code:

```
lis = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
update = [4, 2, 2, 4]

for i in range(0, len(update)):
     lis[i] = update[i]

print(lis)
```