# list extend() to index, inserting list elements not only to the end

Tags: python, list, insert

I'm looking for the most pythonic way to implement a version of the list `extend` function, where it extends to a given index instead of the end of the list.

```
a_list = [ "I", "rad", "list" ]                                                       
b_list = [ "am", "a" ]
a_list.my_extend( b_list, 1 ) # insert the items from b_list into a_list at index 1

print( a_list ) # would output: ['I', 'am', 'a', 'rad', 'list']
```

Is there a way to do this without building a new list, like this?

```
a_list = [ "I", "rad", "list" ]
b_list = [ "am", "a" ]
c_list = []

c_list.extend( a_list[:1] )
c_list.extend( b_list     )
c_list.extend( a_list[1:] )

print( c_list ) # outputs: ['I', 'am', 'a', 'rad', 'list']
```

That approach isn't actually so bad, but I have a hunch it could be easier.  Could it?

Comment: Nothing wrong with building a new list, but why are you doing it in steps? It's much simpler than that: `c_list = a_list[:1] + b_list + a_list[1:]`.

Comment: I didn't know + was overloaded for lists.

Comment: I needed the same thing but almost going to ask, instead, for a way to make `insert` to behave adding "unpacked" list elements at index in a similar way `extend` does... the answer would have been the same :-D

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Sure, you can use slice indexing:

```
a_list[1:1] = b_list
```

Just to demonstrate the general algorithm, if you were to implement the `my_extend` function in a hypothetical custom `list` class, it would look like this:

```
def my_extend(self, other_list, index):
    self[index:index] = other_list
```

But don't actually make that a function, just use the slice notation when you need to.

Comment: Hah, I knew it!  I never thought to try that; I just assumed it would place the entire `b_list` into `a_list` at index 1, rather than the elements of `b_list`.  I clearly need to go review the intricacies of slicing.  Thanks much.

Comment: While I like this solution, it goes slightly against Python principles I guess since it's not immediately obvious what's going to happen (not your fault). I wish there was optional argument for extend rather...

Comment: I dunno, I think it's obvious enough once you get used to slice notation. Hopefully `the_list[i:j] = other_list` makes sense for `i < j`, and this is the natural limit of what happens as `j - i` approaches zero from above. Now, if we were talking about the case `i > j` (like `the_list[5:3] = other_list`) then I would definitely agree that it's not intuitively obvious what should happen, but I don't think that syntax actually works anyway.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky `list[i:j] = list2` does work for `i > j`, but it simply inserts list2's items at index `i`.  No items are removed or "overwritten".

Comment: @JerryMa In your example, `i < j`.  I stated only that `i > j` inserts but does not overwrite.  For example: `a=[1, 2, 3]` and `a[2:1]=[4, 5]` will give `[1, 2, 4, 5, 3]`

Comment: Never really liked the slice indices referring to the gaps between the elements, but now all is forgiven because it allows you to do this! Awesome!

Comment: `a_list[1:1]` returns an empty list `[]`. Why does this method works?