# How to append elements inside a list as a list?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists named `queries_fetcher_list` and `reftable_column_name`.

Now I need to perform the operation of taking an element from `a` and `b`, and make it as a tuple with `zip()`.

This is the query for doing that:

```
some_list = []
for i in range (len(reftable_column_name)):
    for row in queries_fetcher_list[i]:
        some_list.append(dict(zip(reftable_column_name[i], row)))
```

Now I need that result to be append like this:

```
[[{first element}], [{second element}]]
```

What I need to do now is every time when a zip operation is performed that element has to append as a separate list, i.e. list inside a list, like this:

```
a = [] 
a = [['one'], ['two'], ['three']]
```

- `queries_fetcher_list` contains a list of data that are retrived from an MySQL query retrieved with `cursor.fetchall()`.
- `reftable_column_name` is a list contains the column names of a table retrived with `cursor.description()`.

Comment: give us an example data sample. what do reftable_column_name and queries_fetcher_list contain. are they always the same length? demonstrate an input list, and desired output so that we can better understand this question

Comment: As per your suggestion I have edited.

Comment: perhaps this is what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748063/what-is-the-syntax-to-insert-one-list-into-another-list-in-python

Comment: No, What I want to achieve is
a = [ ] 
for i in somerange:
        a.append(i)

Expected output:
a = [ ['first'], ['second'], ['third'] ]

Comment: But `dict(zip(reftable_column_name[i], row))` is a `dict`, it doesn't have elements as a list does, only keys and values. Are your 'first', 'second' etc keys or values?

Answer (score 0):

`some_list.append([dict(zip(reftable_column_name[i], row))])`
will append single-element lists containing your dict.

Answer (score 0):

define a list and everytime when elements got append into it free it, means empty it,now you can achieve what you want,eveytime when an element is appended into a list the list will be flushed and becomes an empty list but make sure to add your elements like this "list(your_element)".