# Is there a dict.update(sub_dict) function for list in Python? (When the list is empty)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Suppose a list in Python -> mylist:

```
mylist = []
```

I want to now take input from users and update the values afterward in mylist:

```
input1 = ["xyz","wyh",34]
print mylist
Output: [["xyz","wyh",34]]

input2 = ["yo","hey",657]
print mylist
output: [["xyz","wyh",34],["yo","hey",657]]
```

append() only works when list has some values already.

Comment: ... `list.append`?

Comment: Yea, I'm not sure what the confusion is...perhaps we should link the documentation?

Comment: The Python documentation involving list is [over here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: Also you may want to tag the question with [tag:python-2.7] or [tag:python-3.x].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the syntax to insert one list into another list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748063/what-is-the-syntax-to-insert-one-list-into-another-list-in-python)

Comment: I would flag it as well but I don't have any more flags :(

Comment: I am sorry folks I couldn't put up my question correctly before. please check the correct version of what I want to ask! Thanks!.

Comment: This is still a poor question. Many such answers are available on Stack Overflow. Please read the guidelines before asking more questions.

Comment: For updating list options are there like append, extend, insert which are not useful for my case, unfortunately. Can you help me with a solution? :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use [list.append](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```
 mylist.append(["L","M",56])
 (or)
 mylist+[["L","M",56]]
```

Comment: talk about low effort answers -_-

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise  you take a look through [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) to see what exactly you need. It sounds like what you want is list.append() however.

```
mylist = [["X","Y",12], ["A","B",23]]
mylist.append(["L","M",56])
```

Comment: What if the list value is null, then it won't append. What in such cases?

Comment: You should initialize the list at first with mylist = [] if you don't have any initial values. Append will work on any list, even if it's empty