# How to combine certain columns from one data frame to another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, data-science

How to add three columns from one data frame to another at a certain position?
I want to add these columns after a specific column? DF1=['C','D'] after
columns A and B in DF2. So how to join columns in between other columns in
another dataframe.

```
df1=pd.read_csv(csvfile)
df2=pd.read_csv(csvfile)

df1['C','D','E'] to df2['K','L','A','B','F']

so it looks like df3= ['K','L','A','B','C','D','F']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for change order of columns:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).reindex(['K','L','A','B','C','D'], axis=1)
```

---

More general solution:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['H','G','C','D','E'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['K','L','A','B','F'])
    
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
c = df3.columns.difference(['C', 'D'], sort=False)
pos = c.get_loc('B')  + 1
c = list(c)
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/3748092/2901002
c[pos:pos] = ['C', 'D']
df3 = df3.reindex(c, axis=1)
print (df3)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [H, G, E, K, L, A, B, C, D, F]
Index: []
```

Comment: what do if a value error, duplicated values in index

Comment: @keenQuestions What are duplicates columns? Need merge by them, so instead `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)` need `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['col1' , 'col2'], how='left')` if duplicated columns,  it means in both Dataframes are `col1, col2`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df3=pd.DataFrame()
df3[['K','L','A','B']]=df2[['K','L','A','B']]
df3[['C','D','E']]=df1[['C','D','E']]
```

Finally:

```
df3=df3[['K','L','A','B','C','D']]
```

OR

```
df3=df3.loc[:,['K','L','A','B','C','D']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
pd.merge([df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True]).[['K','L','A','B','C','D']]
```

or simply use join which is left by deafult

```
df1.join(df2)[['K','L','A','B','C','D']]
```